# Why does callr does not find myFunction?

Tags: r, function, callr

I'm working with a few thousand gig-size json files. Rather than manipulating them in my local workspace, I want to push them to child R processes where the gc() problems disappear when the child R session closes. And, perhaps, I can handle two or three asynchronously, allowing me to take advantage of multiple processors.

But I can't get the simple example to work.

```
myFunction <- function(dataPath, fileId) {
  Sys.sleep(10)
  paste0(dataPath, fileId)
  }

dataPath <- "./"
fileId <- "file01"

filePath <- myFunction(dataPath, fileId)
filePath

filePath <- callr::r(function(dataPath, fileId) myFunction(dataPath, fileId), args = list(dataPath, fileId))
filePath
```

myFunction(), executed in the Global environment, works fine.

callr() does not find myFunction() in the Global environment, even though it shows in ls() and in the object list window.

### Error:
! in callr subprocess.
Caused by error in `myFunction(dataPath, fileId)`:
! could not find function "myFunction"

Backtrace:

1. callr::r(function(dataPath, fileId) myFunction(dataPath, fileId), …
2. callr:::get_result(output = out, options)
3. callr:::throw(callr_remote_error(remerr, output), parent = fix_msg(remerr[[3]]))

---

Subprocess backtrace:

1. base::.handleSimpleError(function (e) …
2. global h(simpleError(msg, call))

I tried another formulation:

```
filePath <- callr::r(myFunction(dataPath, fileId), args = list(dataPath, fileId))
filePath
```

myFunction() does execute in the child R process but fails on return

Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) :
no("func") || is.function(func) is not TRUE

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) Beagle Scouts
- RStudio 2023.06.2+561 "Mountain Hydrangea"
- callr 3.7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`callr::r` sets up a new session with nothing in it except what you pass in the call.  In particular, functions defined in the global environment are not copied there unless you do it explicitly.

So this should work:

```
filePath <- callr::r(function(dataPath, fileId, fn) 
                       fn(dataPath, fileId), 
                     args = list(dataPath, fileId, myFunction))
```

The idea is to pass `myFunction` as an argument named `fn` to the anonymous function that `callr::r` executes.  `callr::r` will serialize it and pass it to the new process.

Comment: And, a word about `, fn) fn(dataPath, fileId)`, okay, I see it now, it is positional-ish, but still seems slippery, and `fn` could be nearly any char that is finally clarified in `args=list(`, that must be found in the prior global, so I guess, is 'function' going to be last, after inputs... in `callr::r(`? Sorry to sound incoherent, but function last, then repeated in args as it's path name name in global. It is just not very clear how this approach to anonymous looks like other anonymous functions.

Comment: @Chris, it can be in any position, with whatever name you like.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly.  

For anyone else following this solution, go through your `myFunction` and make sure that R functions are fully enumerated as `package::function`.

Comment: So, `myFunction`, contains `base::Sys.sleep`, `base::paste0` as guard rails. Got it.